# How to change role from member to admin in Apple developer program?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

I can see my email ID not in Admin role but just as member in **people tab**. So the one in agent role resent me invitation with Admin role. Even though I accepted that, I did not see my role changed from member to Admin. So I followed a suggestion on a forum, suggested to **change role in iTunesConnect**. So the agent added my role in iTunes connect with admin role and resent invitation. Now I can see my role in iTunes connect as 'admin' role. But in people tab in apple developer account my role is still in member. Can you please suggest me how to change my role here to admin?

Comment: iTunes connect accounts and the Apple developer accounts are two different things. One has no effect whatsoever on the other. I don't know why your agent sent you an invite when you are already a member - they could have simply just edited your status directly to upgrade it

Comment: Where should I ask the team agent to edit the status? Since I couldn't see the page where it can be edited, I couldn't guide him proper. Can I have a link where that can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending a new invitation is not the right approach.

Someone with admin or team agent role needs to edit your existing user to "Change to Admin".

https://developer.apple.com/account/#/people/YOUR_TEAM_ID_HERE

[image]

Comment: Where should I ask the team agent to edit my user to add admin permissions? Since I couldn't see the page where it can be edited, I couldn't guide him proper. Can I have a link where that can be done?

Comment: Greaat! Thank you!